# Firefox Lightbeam API

Tags: firefox-addon

I am sure you guys have heard about Mozilla Firefox's LightBeam technology which graphically shows you the third party websites connected to your website. I would like to do something similar to that. Is there an API that I could use? Has anyone of you familiar with such an API?

Also, if there is something similar to Lightbeam that anyone of you might be using, then I'll appreciate if you can let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lightbeam (formerly Collusion) is an Add-on SDK extension, written in Javascript. I don't think it offers an official API you could interact with, and uses itself only APIs Firefox/Gecko provides plus some third party JS libraries such as `d3`.

But it is [open source](https://github.com/mozilla/lightbeam), so you're free to study the code, make pull requests and borrow stuff for your own projects.